# iPhone UI Offset Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface

I have an iPhone app and for some reason it is moving all the UI elements up the height of the status bar, and they are going under the status bar.

And I have set up the UI with Interface Builder

Answer (score 0):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486596/how-to-remedy-a-uinavigationbar-overlapping-the-top-of-my-uiscrollview/2488405#2488405) yesterday. Likely the solution for you is also similar.

Open up the view's .xib in Interface Builder, and Bring up the Attributes Inspector (Cmd-1). Then make sure the Simulated User Interface Elements setting for Status Bar is **not** set to None.

Comment: I tried this, and its still doing it, the status bar is  set to grey.